# Maximize the eclipse editor on open

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When the eclipse editor is opened initially i.e if the workspace is opened for the first time the Eclipse editor will not occupy full screen. Manually the user should maximize the editor. So do we have any option to occupy full screen on open itself. Instead user is manually maximizing the editor.

Comment: Are you asking if you can write a plug-in to do this?

Comment: My question was when the eclipse ide is opened for the first time u will have the welcome page the eclipse ide will not fit the screen we should maximize it manually once the workspace layout is save from next time it will fit the screen

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently referring to the "editor view", not the "eclipse editor".

The simple answer is that Eclipse keeps track of your window layout.  If you start eclipse, then maximize the editor view, and then restart, you'll find that the editor is maximized on open.

I know of no way to automatically start with a maximized editor view, ignoring the previous layout.

Comment: The question isn't about window managers, it is about an Eclipse based editor opening inside Eclipse - Eclipse manages this not the window manager (and it doesn't remember maximize settings).

Comment: Ok. You used unconventional terms for what you're talking about, so that wasn't quite clear. The answer for that is similar. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could force an editor to be maximized by using an `IPartListener2` in a plug-in to listen to the various part events. When you find an editor you want to maximize being opened you can use something like:

```java
IWorkbenchPartReference editorRef = ... part reference to zoom

IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.toggleZoom(editorRef);
```